# Often TimeoutException when using infinispan for http session clustering and caching

Tags: java, infinispan, jgroups, timeoutexception

I have two servers that need to do http session clustering and caching. Each server has serveral nodes that need to share session.But when in process of forming cluster ,it often happens that each server cannot get the other server's correct node names and shows a set of random letters and nums.Just like this:

**2019-11-13 00:28:32,973 INFO   [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport]  ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [12dshost10-14444|11] (12) [12dshost10-14444, 12dhost10-27717, b5f9d81c-046d-bbc5-7de0-0fe99cce2e53, ce824896-df27-fef0-5872-857335dd9ce0, aeec4fab-e57d-2e99-3e06-834c998ee897, b857e4c0-abe4-e989-bc4c-2ab05b60dc12, ca6a9e84-c9ca-3fad-lf20-787539477a2f, 12dshost11-28633, 12dshost10-24663, 12dshost10-3048, 12dshost10-14948, 12dshost10-47369]**

In this case, "*12dshost10*" represents local server, which has all node names correct, "*12dshost11*" represents remote server, and other abnormal nodenames are actually from *12dshost11*". I dont know why they become this.

Under the circumstance, this cluster cannot work functionally, when it comes to the process of session caching, these abnormal nodes always throws TimeoutException after a 15 seconds waiting.It seems like it's impossible to communicate with these abnormal nodes. Within this period of time, all my request will also be blocked until Exception throw. I read the tutorial of infinispan, but fail to find a way to make session caching to be asynchronous and also fail to find out why these abnormal nodes appear. Does anyone have such issues?

This is my configuration for infinispan and cache.

```
<infinispan>
<global>
   <transport>
       <properties>
            <property name="configurationFile" value="cache-web-session-jgroups.xml"/>
            <property name="channelLookup" value="com.wjw.aos.cache.impl.infinispan.InfinispanJGroupsChannelLookup"/>
        </properties>
    </transport>
    <globalJmxStatistics
        allowDuplicateDomains="true"
        enabled="true"
        jmxDomain="org.infinispan"
        cacheManagerName="SampleCacheManager"/>
</global>
<default>
    <clustering mode="replication">
        <sync/>
    </clustering>
    <jmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
</default>
<namedCache name="transactional-type">
    <transactional
        transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup"
        syncRollbackPhase="true"
        syncCommitPhase="true"
        cacheStopTimeout="30000"
        uselPcForAutoCommitTransactions="true"
        autoCommit="true"
        lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"
        useEagerLocking="true"
        useSynchronization="true"
        transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL"
        />
        <clustering mode="replication">
        <sync/>
        </clustering>
</namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

And configuration for jgroups is as below.

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.0.xsd">
    <TCP loopback="true"
        bind_addr="$(cache.websessions.jgroups.bind.ip)"
        bind_port="$(cache.websessions.jgroups.bind.port)"
        recv_buf_size="20M"
        send_buf_size"640k"
        discard_incompatible_packets="true"
        max_bundle_size="64K"
        max_bundle_timeout="2=300"
        timer_type="new"
        timer.min_threads="4"
        timer.max_threads="10"
        timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
        timer.queue_max_size="500"
        thread_pool.enabled="true"
        thread_pool.min_threads="2"
        thread_pool.max_threads="30"
        thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
        thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
        thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
        thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"
        oob_thread_pool.min_threads="2"
        oob_thread_pool.max_threads="30"
        oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
        oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
        oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
        oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"/>
    <TCPGOSSIP initial_hosts="$(cache.websession.jgroups.members)"/>
    <MERGE2 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD timeout=3000" max_tries="3"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>
    <pbcast.NAKACK
        use_mcast_xmit="false"
        retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200,2400,4800"
        discard_delivered_msgs="false"/>
    <UNICAST2 timeout="300,600,1200"
              stable_interval="5000"
              max_bytes="1m"/>
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500" desired_avg_gossip="5000" max_bytes="1m"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="3000" view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="200k" min_threshold="0.20"/>
    <MFC max_credits="200k" min_threshold="0.20"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60000"/>
    <RSVP timeout="60000" resend_interval="500" ack_on_delivery="false"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a really ancient version of Infinispan. Can't you consider an upgrade ?

Comment: yeah, it's an ancient version 6.0.2. And more desperately, I cannot easily do the updates cos our software is used for business for years and our customers can hardly agree to that suggestion. They probably agree to do some patches.  So I have to try to dig into this problem and fix it without updating. Only if it is a known fixed problem in newer version can I suggest to do the update

Comment: The problem is a polluted view. I see you are using TCPGOSSIP. Could you perhaps use an alternate discovery protocol such as TCP_PING ?

Comment: From the tuturiol of Infinispan, it's best for TCP_PING to set all the nodes when initiate a cluster. However, it's different from my original cluster model. Usually I have two servers. Server A cannot see the nodes on Server B. The only connection between server A and B, is that when all the nodes on Server B begin to initiate the cluster, they all add one same node from Server A. In this way can nodes on Server A and Server B combine to form one cluster. So I think it's the most appropriate way to use TCPGOSSIP based on such circumstance.

Comment: As you said the problem was a polluted view, so could you tell me how does it happen? And how to avoid it? Thanx.